# Second option false

Tags: php

how would I set this so that my if statements only works if the second option is not set.

```
$options[options1] && $options[option2] 
  {
    // this would be evaluated
  }
```

So what I need is for this to work only if the first of these options is true and the second is false. They are both coming from the database and the second option is a string value.

Comment: Do you want the `if` statement to be `true` of `$options[option2]` is an empty string?

Comment: yes if that is empty I want to be able to run the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be evaluated if `$options[option2]` evaluates to false:

```
if($options[options1] && !$options[option2]) 
  {
    // this would be evaluated
  }
```

This will be evaluated if it is not set

```
if($options[options1] && !isset($options[option2]) )
  {
    // this would be evaluated
  }
```

This is a nicer version of the first:

```
if($options[options1] && (!isset($options[option2] || !$options[option2])) 
  {
    // this would be evaluated
  }
```

Be careful of the string `"0"`. It is evaluated as `FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

```
   if($options[options1] && (!isset($options[option2]))) {
        // this would be evaluated
      }
```